# ¿Cómo conseguir efecto hover sobre imagenes cargadas de la base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, hover

Estoy haciendo un sitio con Drupal. Tengo un listado de imágenes que se cargan de la base de datos y quisiera que una cambie por otra al hacer hover sobre la 1era. Intenté hacerlo con onmouseover y onmouseout pero solo conseguí que se mostraran ambas a la vez. Mi código:

```
  foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
    $img1 = render(file_create_url($value->uri));

    $img2 = render(file_create_url($records1[$i]->uri));

     <a href="" onmouseover="document.my_image.src = ''<?php print $img1;?>''"
               onmouseout="document.my_image.src = ''<?php print $img2;   ?>''" ><img name="my_image" src=<?php print $img1; ?>  ></a>
  }
```

Alguna idea de cómo lograrlo? Gracias.

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mas la funcionalidad que buscas hacer con la lista de imágenes.

Comment: Tengo dos listados de imágenes de igual cantidad de imágenes cada uno. Yo deseo que en un inicio se muestren las de un listado y que al pasar el puntero sobre una de las que está visibles entonces esa se esconda y se muestre la que le corresponde del segundo listado. Ambos listados son cargados de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con CSS es muy simple y no necesitás JavaScript.

El siguiente es un ejemplo simple para mostrarte la técnica. También podés usar las imágenes como fondos de DIVs con el alto y ancho pre-establecidos.

```css
.imagen .activa { display:none; }
.imagen:hover .normal { display:none; }
.imagen:hover .activa { display:initial; }
```

```html
<div class="imagen">
<img class="normal" src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/animals" alt="" />
<img class="activa" src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/architecture" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funcionó casi como yo quería, solo que la segunda imagen, al mostrarse se corre hacia abajo, es decir, no se muestra en el lugar exacto donde estaba la primera. Tal vez afectadas por alguna clase que las engloba, me fijaré. Igual excelente. Gracias.